# Failure to Match Template Using Function Pointer as Argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am attempting to write a function which will operate on a std::map of any key and class pointer given to it, and create a new std::map with an index based on the return value of a function in the class. Essentially, a template function to re-index a map based on a function in its contained class. However, I am having compiler errors when trying to invoke the function.

```
template<class AnyType, class ValueType, class FunctionType>
AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType> reindex( const AssocArray<AnyType, ValueType>& original, FunctionType (*getterFunction)() ) {
    AssocArray<FunctionType, ValueType> ret;
    FunctionType index;
    for(typename AssocArray<AnyType,ValueType>::const_iterator it = original.begin(); it!=original.end(); it++) {
        index = ((*it->second).*getterFunction)();
        ret[index] = it->second;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Invoked by:

```
floatIndexed = reindex( intIndexed, &test::getB );
```

Where getB is of float type.

This results in the compiler error:

```
src/World.cpp:78:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘reindex(std::map<int, onathacar::test*>&, float (onathacar::test::*)())’
src/World.cpp:78:50: note: candidate is:
./include/Types.h:123:36: note: template<class AnyType, class ValueType, class FunctionType> std::map<PreservedType, ValueType> onathacar::reindex(const std::map<LookupType, ValueType>&, FunctionType (*)())
```

I have tried different variations of this, including using "FunctionType (ValueType::*getterFunction)()" and changing "AssocArray" to "AssocArray". The only one which worked added a fourth template argument:

```
template<class AnyType, class ValueType, class FunctionType, class SomeType>
AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType> reindex( const AssocArray<AnyType, ValueType>& original, FunctionType (SomeType::*getterFunction)() ) {
```

However, this seems like it would potentially allow functions that are not actually members of ValueType to be called, and so I would prefer some other option. I am not even sure what is wrong, as it appears the templates match, at least with the addition of "ValueType::". Why does the call not match the template, and is there a way to fix it without a fourth templated type?

For more context, [Header Containing Implementation](http://pastebin.com/jarLmacF) and [Calling Function](http://pastebin.com/jT96gYWG).

Comment: Can you tell-me the error you get when you try FunctionType (ValueType::*getterFunction)() without the 4th template parameter ?

Comment: Your code expects a function pointer and you pass it a member function pointer. Which aspect of this specifically are you confused about?

Comment: The FunctionType (ValueType::*getterFunction)() error it seems was because I forgot to include change the "AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType>" return value to "AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType*>", which works;

`template<class AnyType, class ValueType, class FunctionType> AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType*> reindex( const AssocArray<AnyType, ValueType*>& original, FunctionType (ValueType::*getterFunction)() )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that `reindex` implies that the value types are values, but you use them as pointers:

```
AssocArray<float, test*> floatIndexed;
floatIndexed = reindex( intIndexed, &test::getB );
```

The second is that `reindex`'s second parameter needs to be declared as a member function, not a free function. So `reindex` should look like this:

```
template<class AnyType, class ValueType, class FunctionType>
AssocArray<FunctionType,ValueType *> reindex( const AssocArray<AnyType, ValueType *>& original, FunctionType (ValueType:: *getterFunction)() ) {
    AssocArray<FunctionType, ValueType*> ret;
    FunctionType index;
    for(typename AssocArray<AnyType,ValueType*>::const_iterator it = original.begin(); it!=original.end(); it++) {
        index = ((*it->second)->*getterFunction)();
        ret[index] = it->second;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That template/function definition worked. I believe the error was that when I tried ValueType*, I forgot to change it for the return value as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use your `rindex()` function with members but your function is declared to use non-members. This won't work. The reason this won't work is that the you need an object to access either function or data members of a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class A, class B>
class X{
public:

};

class Y{
public:
    int func() { return 42; }
};

template<class A, class B, class C>
X<C,B> reindex( const X<A, B>& original, C (B::*getterFunction)() ) {
    X<C, B> x2;
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    return x2;
}
```

`int main() {
    X x1;
    reindex(x1,&Y::func);
    return 0;`

}

This works and gives perfectly valid results.

The problem with your call  AssocArray intIndexed, is the fact that you are trying to pass &test::getB as the getter function, which assumes valueType = test, where as your actual value type, is test*.